# How to implement parts of member functions of a Class in a static library while the rest functions implemented in a cpp file?

Tags: c++, compilation, static-libraries

I have a C++ `Class A` like this:

```
// in header file A.h
class A
{
public:
    void foo1();
    void foo2();
private:
    double m_a;
};


// in cpp file A1.cpp
void A::foo1(){
    m_a = 0;  //do something with m_a
}

// in cpp file A2.cpp
void A::foo2(){
    foo1();  // call foo1
}

// in cpp file main.cpp
int main(){
    A obj;
    obj.foo2();
    return 0;
}
```

In my occasion, the function `foo1` and `foo2` are implemented by two different people. For some reasons, I need to hide the implementation of `foo1` so that the people who code A2.cpp cannot fetch the source code of `foo1`, and at the same time he can use `Class A` in his own application (like `main.cpp` above).

I tried to archive A1.cpp as a static library, and of course, an *'unresolved external symbol'* error for `foo2` occurred.

I built my static library using CMake plugins in Visual Studio 2019, and my CMakeLists.txt is like:

```
add_library (my_lib STATIC A1.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_lib PUBLIC path/to/A.h)
```

Is there any solution or workaround for this issue?

Comment: How did you build the static library? A library, as the name suggests, is just a collection of object files. It's okay for those object files to depend on things that aren't part of the library. Those things have to be added when you link the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile A1.cpp without linking, which will give you a compiled object file, A1.o. You can hand this off, so the developers for A2.cpp won't be able to see the source, but will be able to link your object file to build the final project.

With g++, that could look like:

#### A.h

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo1();
    void foo2();
private:
    double m_a;
};
```

#### A1.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>

void A::foo1() {
    std::cout << "foo1 called!" << std::endl;
    m_a = 72;
}
```

#### A2.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>

void A::foo2() {
    std::cout << "foo2 called!" << std::endl;
    foo1();
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo2();
}
```

### Building the project

If you're using g++, then...

```
g++ -c A1.cpp
```

This will compile but not link A1.cpp, giving you the object file A1.o. You can hand that file off so that the other developers can build the whole project with

```
g++ main.cpp A1.o A2.cpp
```

Comment: Finally, I found it was my fault using wrong cmake commands. The 'unresolved external symbol' error is no longer reported after I removed instruction of ```add_executable``` before ```add_library```, which use the same header and source files. Although there is an option in VS that only build the static library, it seems the executable program would also be linked. Thank you anyway!